# why using push instruction instead of overwriting memory location %esp points causes ambiguous behavior in a recursive procedure

Tags: assembly, x86

I have following piece of assembly:

```
recursive:
pushl   %ebp
movl    %esp, %ebp
subl    $40, %esp
cmpl    $0, 8(%ebp)
jne .L6
movl    $0, %eax
jmp .L7
.L6:
movl    8(%ebp), %eax
movl    (%eax), %eax
movl    %eax, -12(%ebp)
movl    8(%ebp), %eax
movl    4(%eax), %eax
movl    %eax, (%esp)
call    recursive
movl    %eax, -16(%ebp)
movl    -16(%ebp), %eax
movl    -12(%ebp), %edx
leal    (%edx,%eax), %eax
.L7:
leave
ret
```

When I try to push %eax instead of moving it to mem address where esp points, my program isn't working properly. I think it has to do with stack size which is 40, because when I make it 36, it works fine with push instruction. However, I don't understand why this is important because all memory addresses I used in assembly are relative to esp and ebp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you have a bug somewhere else or your stack is not big enough to handle the recursion. I see no problem in the presented code.

Comment: presented code is OK, but when I write 'push %eax' instead of  movl %eax, (%esp), it doesn't work properly. I'm sure there is no bug but maybe stack size cannot handle recursion as you said, But I don't understand why it is not big enough to handle recursion, I have no lots of variables and biggest offset from frame pointer is just 16

Comment: @bfaskiplar: I don't know why `pushl %eax` instead of `movl %eax, (%esp)` makes the program fail. It should not. I tried the same(\*) routine both ways and it worked for me just fine. (\*) Same = converted to intel syntax and 16 bit. It just works. I have a guess. You may be overwriting some data on the stack when calling `recursive` and it's being overwritten differently depending on how `recursive` uses the stack. Look for all routines that may create/leave data on the stack and return its address to the caller. That's a big no-no.

Comment: It turned out that I do not allocate enough space to stack at first, when I increased it to 300 from 100 bytes, and it is resolved.